# Exact value of $27\pi\tan\beta$ with $\cos\beta=\frac15$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The inferior base of the cylinder is contained in the $xy$-plane and
>   is centred at the origin $O$. The segment $OA$ is the radius of the base and $A=(0,3,0)$. $\angle AOB=\alpha$ with $\alpha\in(0,\frac\pi2)$.
>   [image]
>   The cylinder's volume is
>   $$V(\alpha)=27\pi\tan\alpha$$
>   Find the exact value of $V(\beta)$ if $\cos\beta=\frac15$.

I tried
$$\tan\beta=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}=5\sin\beta$$
What next?

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\tan \beta &=& \sqrt{\tan^2 \beta} \\
&=& \sqrt{\sec^2 \beta - 1} \\
&=& \sqrt{\dfrac1{\cos^2\beta}-1} \\
&=& \sqrt{25-1} \\
&=& \sqrt{24} \\
27\pi\tan\beta &=& 54\sqrt6\pi
\end{array}$$

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks, corrected.